# Divide a GeoTIFF image into regular grids and compute mean values

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, gdal

How can I subset a GeoTIFF (single band) image (say, 1000 by 1000 pixels) into regular square grids (say, 50 by 50 pixels; 400 grid objects in total); and calculate mean latitude, mean longitude, and mean DN value for each object? Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

The input data is just the imagery,for example as downloaded from:
http://eoimages.gsfc.nasa.gov/images/imagerecords/57000/57752/land_shallow_topo_2048.tif

This can be opened into python using gdal as folows:

```
import gdal
geotiff = gdal.Open ('land_shallow_topo_2048.tif')
colum_numbers,row_numbers,band_numbers=geotiff.RasterXSize,geotiff.RasterYSize,geotiff.RasterCount
print (colum_numbers,row_numbers,band_numbers)
2048 1024 3
```

Comment: what did you try so far? what is your datastructure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Numpy reshaping trick to do this. You can reshape your original 2D array to a 4D array where all cells which would fall in a single 50*50 grid are put into two unique dimensions. Calling any function on these axis will give you the aggregated result.

Lets make a sample 2D array:

```
n = 1000
grid_size = 20

grid = np.arange(n*n).reshape(n,n)
```

Then calculate the aggregation factor and the number of grids in both dimensions:

```
factor = n / grid_size
yblocks, xblocks = np.array(grid.shape) / factor
```

You can then reshape the original `grid` array to 4 dimensions and apply the `mean` on the second and fourth dimension.

```
grid_small = grid.reshape(yblocks, factor, xblocks, factor).mean(axis=3).mean(axis=1)
```

You can test it by slicing a few of the grids yourself and applying the mean on them with:

```
assert(grid[:factor,:factor].mean() == grid_small[0,0])
assert(grid[-factor:,-factor:].mean() == grid_small[-1,-1])
```

The results and difference visualized:
[image]

Comment: @ Rutger Kassies Thank you for your efforts. Your method can be applied for calculating mean of the DN values of the bands. However, how to calculate mean of latitutude and longitude for each grid?

Comment: @tester3, that a completely different question. You asked for the mean within 50*50 blocks in a 1000*1000 image. Its probably best to just open a different question for it, that makes it much easier to find for people with the same question.

Answer (score 1):

A fast and convenient way to do this is to generate an integral image (AKA summed area table). You can then compute the mean in any rectangular patch with four look-ups.

If you give more details in your question (for example, what is the format of your data as Python code?) I can give more specific advice.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed_area_table

Comment: Thank you for your response to my question. I have updated the question for you @Mr E